# Adding columns on menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this menu in https://codepen.io/ettrics/pen/ZYqKGb where I only have 5 menu titles. Now, I need it to be 6. I added strip6 on my css but the menu didn't work as expected and has been messed up. The title of the 6th column went in with the first column and the strip number 6 isn't displaying.

How can I add another column title? What should be added/edited on my css? Please help

```js
  var Expand = (function() {
  var tile = $('.strips__strip');
  var tileLink = $('.strips__strip > .strip__content');
  var tileText = tileLink.find('.strip__inner-text');
  var stripClose = $('.strip__close');
  
  var expanded  = false;

  var open = function() {
      
    var tile = $(this).parent();

      if (!expanded) {
        tile.addClass('strips__strip--expanded');
        // add delay to inner text
        tileText.css('transition', 'all .5s .3s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        stripClose.addClass('strip__close--show');
        stripClose.css('transition', 'all .6s 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        expanded = true;
      } 
    };
  
  var close = function() {
    if (expanded) {
      tile.removeClass('strips__strip--expanded');
      // remove delay from inner text
      tileText.css('transition', 'all 0.15s 0 cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
      stripClose.removeClass('strip__close--show');
      stripClose.css('transition', 'all 0.2s 0s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)')
      expanded = false;
    }
  }

    var bindActions = function() {
      tileLink.on('click', open);
      stripClose.on('click', close);
    };

    var init = function() {
      bindActions();
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  }());

Expand.init();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel&display=swap');
{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.strips {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
 .strips__strip {
  will-change: width, left, z-index, height;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
  left: 60vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
  left: 80vw;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
  left: 100vw;
}

 .strips__strip:nth-child(1) .strip__content {
  background:#29363B;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip1;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(2) .strip__content {
  background: #EA495F;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip2;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(3) .strip__content {
  background: #F4837D;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip3;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(4) .strip__content {
  background: #FAA664;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip4;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(5) .strip__content {
  background: #99B998;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip5;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
 .strips__strip:nth-child(6) .strip__content {
  background: red;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip5;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip {
   min-height: 20vh;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
   top: 20vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
   top: 40vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
   top: 60vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
   top: 80vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
 
  .strips__strip:nth-child(6) {
   top: 100vh;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }
}
 .strips .strip__content {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(3) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
 .strips .strip__content:before {
  <!-- content: ""; -->
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.05;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scaleY(1) translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips .strip__inner-text {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 .strips__strip--expanded {
  width: 100%;
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: default;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip--expanded {
   min-height: 100vh;
 }
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.05;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__title {
  opacity: 0;
}
 .strips__strip--expanded .strip__inner-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
 .strip__title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strip__title {
   font-size: 28px;
 }
}
 .strip__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
  top: 3vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
 .strip__close--show {
  opacity: 1;
}
 @keyframes strip1 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip2 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip3 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip4 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}
 @keyframes strip5 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

@keyframes strip6 {
  0% {
   transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
 }
  100% {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
}

 body {
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
 h1, h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
}
 .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
 h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
 p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}
p {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent 5px
     );
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 100%;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  background:
     linear-gradient(
       to right,
       var(--mainColor) 0%,
       var(--mainColor) 5px,
       transparent
     );
}

:root {
  --mainColor: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="strips">
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Lorem">Awesome</h1>
      </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Ipsum">Words</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Dolor">Go</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Sit">Inside</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Amet">Here</h1>
    </div>
  </article>
  <i class="fa fa-close strip__close"></i>
  
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Add">Additional Column</h1>
    </div>
  </article>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have to update the left attribute to expand all your element.
The origin example have 5 items so each item have width of 100/5 = 20vw
If you want to add 1 more item, so each item have width of 100/6 = 16.6666vw

```
&:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0;
}

&:nth-child(2) {
  left: 17vw;
}

&:nth-child(3) {
  left: 34vw;
}

&:nth-child(4) {
  left: 51vw;
}

&:nth-child(5) {
  left: 68vw;
}

&:nth-child(6) {
  left: 85vw;
}
```